# QuantLib FittedBondDiscountCurve does not produce expected rates

Tags: programming, fixed-income, bond, quantlib, yield-curve

I am using the QuantLib library to fit yield curves. For a $\\\$100$ face bond, with price equal to $\\\$100$, and coupon equal to $\\\$0$, I would expect it to provide a zeroRate of $0.0\%$.

However, it seems that when I also provide it with non-zero coupons at times *beyond* the maturity date, it sometimes returns a zeroRate of $0.0\%$, and sometimes something else.

Consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import QuantLib as ql

calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.Settlement)
today = calendar.adjust(ql.Date(19, 12, 2019))

maturity_list = [ql.Date(19,12,2020),ql.Date(15,4,2021),ql.Date(15,4,2022)]
coupon_list = [0,5.0,4.0]
px_list = [100,100,100]

ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today

pgbs = pd.DataFrame(
    {'maturity' : maturity_list,
    'coupon' : coupon_list,
    'px' : px_list
    })

bondSettlementDays = 0
bondSettlementDate = calendar.advance(
    today,
    ql.Period(bondSettlementDays, ql.Days))

frequency = ql.Annual
dc = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA)

accrualConvention = ql.Unadjusted
convention = ql.Unadjusted
redemption = 100.0

instruments = []
for idx, row in pgbs.iterrows():
    maturity = row.maturity
    schedule = ql.Schedule(
        bondSettlementDate,
        maturity,
        ql.Period(frequency),
        calendar,
        accrualConvention,
        accrualConvention,
        ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
        False)
    helper = ql.FixedRateBondHelper(
            ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(row.px)),
            bondSettlementDays,
            100.0,
            schedule,
            [row.coupon / 100],
            dc,
            convention,
            redemption)

    instruments.append(helper)

params = [bondSettlementDate, instruments, dc]

fittingMethods = {
    'NelsonSiegelFitting': ql.NelsonSiegelFitting(),
}

fittedBondCurveMethods = {
    label: ql.FittedBondDiscountCurve(*params, method)
    for label, method in fittingMethods.items()
}

curve = fittedBondCurveMethods.get('NelsonSiegelFitting')

print('Zero rate: ',curve.zeroRate(maturity_list[0],dc,ql.Compounded,frequency))
```

This returns a zeroRate of $0.00\%$, as I would expect.

If, however, the sixth line of code is replaced by the line `coupon_list = [0,5.0,5.0]`, then all of a sudden it returns a non-zero zeroRate of $1.89\%$!

Could someone please shed some light on this for me?

Many thanks!

NOTE: The code above was adapted from here: *https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/termstructures.html#ql.FittedBondDiscountCurve*.

EDIT1: Attempts I have made to understand this include changing assumptions such as *frequency*, *dc*, *accrualConvention*, and others, with no success.

Comment: My current working assumption is that the new coupon_list mentioned in the question introduces some instability in the Nelson Siegel curve fitting being used ... but I don't know enough about that algorithm to say whether that guess is reasonable or not.

Comment: What is your intended economic meaning of coupon rates past the maturity date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now understand the Nelson-Siegel algorithm, and realize that since the

> fittedBondCurveMethods.get('NelsonSiegelFitting')

line is fitting a model, and not interpolating data, it need not necessarily replicate the yields that were fed to it. I think the specific issue I mentioned above shows that while zcb yields of 0, 5, 4 at the specified dates could be accommodated by a NS model, yields of 0, 5, 5 just could not, and that is fine.